# How to move "+" to right i n css?

Tags: css

[image]

My Css is as below i try to move the "+" icon to the right a bit but failed to move it, can anyone help?

```
.button-sec-icon { 
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    cursor:pointer;  
    background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png") no-repeat left!important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #ca2b2b;
    display: block;
    height: 28px; 
    margin: 10px 0 0 60px;  
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 121px; 
}


.button-sec-icon:hover {
    border :1px solid #888;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: You used the margin tag twice. "margin-right" and "margin". Delete the first "margin-right" and see what happens.

Comment: @ n00b, you're right the margin-right cause the issue. I would like to accept your answer but you put in comment :)

Comment: what is this `.button-sec-icon` class name refers to? Does it refers to the button or some other element? the answers below are assuming that the class name refers to the button element. Also post your related html code..

Comment: @tsohtan I'll add an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the margin tag twice. "margin-right" and "margin". Delete the first "margin-right" and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

```
background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png") no-repeat left!important;
```

So instead of using `left`, use

```
background-position: 10px 0; /* Parameters are X and Y respectively */
```

Comment: i tried change thevalue of X i can see it's move up and down in chrome browser, but when i change Y it doesn't move, any idea?

Comment: @tsohtan http://jsfiddle.net/LXDFF/ set the parameter `px` according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Can you just set the background-position to top right?

```
background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png") top right no-repeat !important;
```

Or even if you need it across a bit, use percentages or fixed widths:

```
background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png") 0 5% no-repeat !important;
background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png") 0 5px no-repeat !important;
```

Comment: I think OP wants to move the background image little right but not completely right. I am not sure though. "_icon to the right a bit_"

Comment: Good point, it does sound like that. Updated explicit width example

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: 10px 0px;
```

This should do the trick, background-position can be used in many ways.
Take a read here:

http://www.css3.com/css-background-position/

Comment: @FaddishWorm There is a hint in this line: `background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/plus.png")`